# DELL iDrac 6 sensors data monitoring

Tags: dell, drac

Hi i was trying to get sensors data directly form iDrac card but no success.

SNMP: iDrac6 is offering only SNMP traps.

Racadm: in some versions of iDrac it was possible to get sensors data but when i type help there is no command regarding sensors.

SSH-SM CLP: I was able to connect to iDRAC but i have no clue how to get sensors information. I tried

> show /admin1/system1/sp1/sensors1

and got

> /admin1/system1/sp1/sensors1
>
> ```
>     properties
>             ElementName = Sensors
>     associations
>             owningcollectionelement :
>                     OwnedElement = /admin1/system1/sp1/sensors1
>                     OwningElement = /admin1/system1/sp1
>             elementconformstoprofile :
>                     ConformantStandard = /admin1/profiles1/profile21
>                     ManagedElement = /admin1/system1/sp1/sensors1
>     targets
>     verbs
>             cd
>             show
>             help
>             version
> ```

Please if somebody knows how to query sensors though SM CLP let me know.

I cant use Dell OM SA becouse of running on ESXi5.0 box.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm in a position like this as well, it seems that (according to documentation) this should be available for monitoring, specifically in the MIB for DELL-RAC; odd.

Comment: Hi at then end, i ended up with IPMI. I call it from perl and parsed the result. That way i could get temperatures, rpms of fans maybe on some servers also raid status, but that wasnt my case.

Comment: Ish; it annoys me to no end that the DRAC MIB's have all kinds of sensors in them but yet it's not available on an IDRAC6 enterprise...